# From template.php to tpl.php

Tags: theming, users, entities

I define variables in `template.php` file `preprocess_page` but it come undefined in `tpl.php` files. What can be a problem? Here is code

template.php file

```
$user_profile = profile2_load_by_user($uid, 'user_profile');
$vars['user_profile'] = $user_profile;
```

tpl.php file

```
print_r($user_profile);
```

Comment: Where is `$uid` coming from? based on the code you have provided, `$uid` is undefined.

Comment: Friend that comes from here   {global $user;
    $uid = user_load($user->uid);}

Comment: Are you sure that you are accessing the variable in the correct tpl.php file?Check the tpl.php name and make sure that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check to see that `profile2_load_by_user` is a function available via a .module file and not something you will need to load via `module_load_include()` - which will load other files, such as .inc files.

Second, check the argument list for the preprocess hook. Did you define it as `&$variables` and mistakenly assign it to `$vars` which would mean nothing in this context? Did you forget to pass by reference via `&` which makes the array  modifiable?

Third, if you just added this code, clear your site caches so the changes are picked up.

Fourth, the function name isn't `preprocess_page`. It should be 
 `MYTHEME_preprocess_page`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is write not one preprocess_page but, many preprocesses depend on page... Say you have user_page page, preprocess should be `theme_name_preprocess_user_page`  or  use `['theme_hook_suggestion'][] = 'tpl.php - name';`